# How to get application roles assigned for current logged on user via C# and GraphServiceClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, msal, entra

I have an ASP.NET 6.0 C# application which is registered in Entra ID, let us say it is called MyApp. In the Azure portal for MyApp, under App registrations, I have used Manage - App roles to define custom roles, Editor and Viewer. Then in Manage - Users and groups I have assigned users and groups to these roles.

In the application code I have a GraphServiceClient. With the following code I can get a collection of AppRoleAssignments, where gs is a GraphServiceClient object:

```
var approles = await gs.Me.AppRoleAssignments.Request().GetAsync();
```

However these AppRoleAssignments are not the custom roles. If the user has a role assigned, there is one AppRoleAssignment that has a ResourceDisplayName of MyApp in the approles collection above, but how can I get the custom roles, Editor or Viewer, assigned to the currently logged in user?

I have looked at this sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles which shows how to set an Authorize attribute using a custom role but I don't want to do that, I want code to list the custom roles in MyApp that are assigned to the current user.

Update: this is one solution

```
 private bool IsCurrentUserInRole(string role)
    {

      foreach (System.Security.Claims.Claim claim in User.Claims)
      {
        if (claim.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role)
        {
          if (claim.Value == role)
          {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
```

I am still not sure how to do it with GraphServiceClient

Comment: we already get the app roles assigned to the user, pls pay attention to the app role id property, you would find it matches the app role you created and assigned. Then I checked in google and I didn't find an api for getting app roles, so that we could use service principle api to get the app role. By the way, the collection we get from `AppRoleAssignments` would return other resources, so that we need to add an if clause to check if this is an app role. If it's an app role, the app role id property should n't have value like `00000-0000`,

Comment: First of all, we are trying to get the app roles assigned to the user, so that we should utilize `query user` api, and we would found we only have [app role assignment api](appRoleId). It only returns app role id but  without app role name. In your requirement, you are trying to check the app role, so that if the role name is necessary, we still need to get the role name by role id, however, we don't have a Graph API for list/get app role. We do have api for listing applications including the app roles they containing, but I think it would bring much effort.